# Ошибка при попытке импорта функции из своего модуля

Tags: python, импорт

[image: Иерархия файлов]

Хочу импортировать из файла **db_connection.py** объект **session** в файл **my_select.py**, но получаю ошибку `'No module named 'database'`.
Пробовал:

```
from .database.db_connection import session
from ..database.db_connection import session
from University_Postgres_SQLAlchemy.database.db_connection import session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При попытке импорта

```py
from .database.db_connection import session
```

У тебя вылетает ошибка `'No module named 'database'` так как в твоем пакете `selects` нету модуля `database`

Правильно будет импортировать без точки

```py
from database.db_connection import session
```

Также можно засунуть в файл `__init__.py` пакета `database`

```py
from .db_connection import session
```

И тогда в `selects` можно имортировать таким образом:

```py
from database import session
```